# Tensorflow - keras - shapes and loss for multilabel classification

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

```
X_np_new.shape, y.shape 

((50876, 2304), (50876, 9))
```

Code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5000, activation='relu', input_dim=X_np_new.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(600, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(X_np_new.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X_np_new, y, epochs=5, batch_size=2000)

preds = model.predict(X_np_new)
```

I get error:

```
 ValueError: Shapes (None, 9) and (None, 2304) are incompatible
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
model.add(Dense(X_np_new.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
```

With

```
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
```

**Explanation:**

Putting `X_np_new.shape[1]` in the last layer means you have `2304` classes because `X_np_new.shape[1]=2304` but you actually have `9` classes that you can get that from `y.shape[1]`.

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 9) and (None, 2304) are incompatible
```

means that your model is expecting labels of Size `[*, 2304]` but your labels size is `[*, 9]`.